# Selecting a date between certain range based on conditions using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am having a little issue with a date generator code below. The list of the code below is to ensure that a random date is selected within the summer months (May, June, July August) for availability.

So what I did is that I say if the current month is less than 5 (less than May), then select a random date between 1st May this year till 31st August this year, else if the current month is past 7 (past July), then select a random date between 1st May next year till 31st August next year.

Now I notice a little glitch in my code I require help with. As I ran the code below today (8th May), it is possible that the date the random generator selects could be in May before today's date. Actually the issue is I don't have anything to handle when I am in the current months. So I think I require a little refactoring.

What i would like is that it checks the current date and if it between May to July (so not less than May or more than July), then check today's date and pick a date between today till the 31st August this year.

My brain has been fried and for some strange reason I am struggling on something which logically makes sense, but I've just been having issues programming it.

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

//def dataSet = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
// Select the current test data line

def dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

def getNumberInRange = { min, max -> new Random().nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min }

def isTodayBeforeMay = { Calendar.MONTH < 5 }

def isTodayAfterJuly = { Calendar.MONTH > 7 }

//Get the number of days between today and given date
def getDifferenceDays = { targetDate, closure ->
    def strDate = closure (targetDate)
    def futureDate = new Date().parse(dateFormat, strDate)
    TimeCategory.minus(futureDate, new Date()).days
}

//Get the offset between today and max date i.e.,31 august
def getOffSetDays = { date ->
    //Need to change the date range if needed.
    //As per OP, May to August is mentioned below
    def max = getDifferenceDays(date) { "${it[Calendar.YEAR]}-08-31" }
    def min = getDifferenceDays(date) { "${it[Calendar.YEAR]}-05-01" }
    getNumberInRange(min, max)

}



def now = new Date()
def nextYearNow = now.updated(year: now[Calendar.YEAR] + 1)

def selected
def finalDate

log.info "Today : $now"
log.info "Next year same date : $nextYearNow"

if (isTodayBeforeMay()) {
    selected = now    
} else if (isTodayAfterJuly()) {
    selected = nextYearNow
} else {
    throw new Error("Not implemented for the days between 1st May to 30th July")
}

def offset = getOffSetDays(selected)

//Add the offset days to now
use(TimeCategory) {
    finalDate = now + offset.days
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to implement the `else` condition instead of `throw new Error(..)` below (code excerpt from the question):

If you read the code, it is crystal clear each condition and error message as place holder for the **unknown data range** in below and which is now you wanted it to be handled.

```
if (isTodayBeforeMay()) {
    selected = now    
} else if (isTodayAfterJuly()) {
    selected = nextYearNow
} else {
    throw new Error("Not implemented for the days between 1st May to 30th July")
}
```

Just add the below statement in the last `else` in place of `threw new Error`

```
selected = getOffSetDays(now)
```

**EDIT:**

You can try quickly online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5131631555772416)</kbd>

EDIT 2: Looks the above is not working at times randomly, so updating the answer:

```groovy
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

def getNumberInRange = { max, min = 1 -> new Random().nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min }

def isTodayBeforeMay = { Calendar.MONTH < 5 }

def isTodayAfterJune = { Calendar.MONTH > 6 }

//Get the number of days between today and given date
def getDifferenceDays = { targetDate, closure ->
    def strDate = closure (targetDate)
    def futureDate = new Date().parse(dateFormat, strDate)
    TimeCategory.minus(futureDate, new Date()).days
}

def getPaddedString = { num, len = 2, padwith = '0' ->
    num.toString().padLeft(len, padwith)
}

//Get the offset between today and max date i.e.,31 august
def getOffSetDays = { date, minMonth = 5, minDay = 1 ->
    //Need to change the date range if needed.
    //As per OP, May to August is mentioned below
    def max = getDifferenceDays(date) { "${it[Calendar.YEAR]}-08-31" }
    def min = getDifferenceDays(date) { "${it[Calendar.YEAR]}-${getPaddedString(minMonth)}-${getPaddedString(minDay)}" }
    getNumberInRange(max, min)
}


def now = new Date()
def nextYearNow = now.updated(year: now[Calendar.YEAR] + 1)

def selected
def finalDate

println "Today : $now"
println "Next year same date : $nextYearNow"

if (isTodayBeforeMay()) {
    selected = now    
} else if (isTodayAfterJune()) {
    selected = nextYearNow
} 

def dayz = getNumberInRange(getDifferenceDays(now) { "${it[Calendar.YEAR]}-08-31" })
def offset = selected ? getOffSetDays(selected) : dayz 
offset = offset > 0 ? offset : now[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]+1

//Add the offset days to now
use(TimeCategory) {
    finalDate = now + offset.days
}
println "Final future date is : $finalDate"
println "Final future date is(formatted) : ${finalDate.format(dateFormat)}"

assert now <= finalDate
```

This <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5204577280327680)</kbd> generate the date 1000 times just to make sure the date is ok.

Comment: Hi Rao, can't believe i didn't think of that. however when trying your line of code, it still chose a date in the past from current date

Comment: It's weird because I ran it and it gives me 6th may 2017 date

Comment: the above solution is not working, still having same issue

Comment: @BruceyBandit, please check EDIT2 now.